# Adding date values to unbalanced panel data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large unbalanced data set where I would like to add 12 additional months to each unique group of identifiers

Here is an example of data:

| X | Y | Z | year_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb | ccc | 2008-09-01 |
| aaa | bbb | ccc | 2008-10-01 |
| aaa | ddd | eee | 2010-06-01 |
| aaa | ddd | eee | 2010-07-01 |
| aaa | ddd | eee | 2010-08-01 |

Here is what I would like the data set to look like:

| X | Y | Z | year_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb | ccc | 2007-09-01 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| aaa | bbb | ccc | 2008-08-01 |
| aaa | bbb | ccc | 2008-09-01 |
| aaa | bbb | ccc | 2008-10-01 |
| aaa | ddd | eee | 2009-06-01 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| aaa | ddd | eee | 2010-05-01 |
| aaa | ddd | eee | 2010-06-01 |
| aaa | ddd | eee | 2010-07-01 |
| aaa | ddd | eee | 2010-08-01 |

I've tried isolating the earliest date for each unique identifier and then adding the date 12 months prior. I then use padr but the results end up adding every day. At least that is what I believe it is doing since this runs for hours.
Here is my code:

```r
test <- date_filler %>% 
  group_by(X, Y, Z) %>%
  do(pad(date_filler, interval = "month"))
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate) # %m-%
dat %>%
  group_by(X, Y, Z) %>%
  summarize(
    year_month = seq(min(year_month) %m-% months(12), max(year_month), by = "month")
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 29 x 4
#    X     Y     Z     year_month
#    <chr> <chr> <chr> <date>    
#  1 aaa   bbb   ccc   2007-09-01
#  2 aaa   bbb   ccc   2007-10-01
#  3 aaa   bbb   ccc   2007-11-01
#  4 aaa   bbb   ccc   2007-12-01
#  5 aaa   bbb   ccc   2008-01-01
#  6 aaa   bbb   ccc   2008-02-01
#  7 aaa   bbb   ccc   2008-03-01
#  8 aaa   bbb   ccc   2008-04-01
#  9 aaa   bbb   ccc   2008-05-01
# 10 aaa   bbb   ccc   2008-06-01
# # ... with 19 more rows
```

---

Data: I pre-converted `year_month` to `Date`-class.

```r
dat <- structure(list(X = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa"), Y = c("bbb", "bbb", "ddd", "ddd", "ddd"), Z = c("ccc", "ccc", "eee", "eee", "eee"), year_month = structure(c(14123, 14153, 14761, 14791, 14822), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you r2evans!